# Do browsers protect from sending multiple requests on multiple fast clicking one link?

Tags: browser, web, hyperlink

Does this protection exists? I click on a link twice in a row fast. Sometimes I am getting only one request, sometimes 2

Answer (score 0):

Did not find any protection from multiple clicking. So, the solution was to hide a link after clicking.

jQuery allows hiding easily